# Unable to generate the sitemap

Tags: magento-1.9, sitemaps, google

Magento fails to generate the sitemap.xml. I get `Unable to generate the sitemap.`.

[image]

I get this exception:

```
2019-02-25T15:00:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULLurl_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%'
 INNER JOIN `magecatalog_category_enti' at line 2, query was: SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `url_rewrite`.`request_path` FROM `magecatalog_category_entity` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `magecore_url_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite` ON url_rewrite.category_id=main_table.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_system=1 AND url_rewrite.store_id = 1 AND url_rewrite.category_id IS NOT NULLurl_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%'
 INNER JOIN `magecatalog_category_entity_int` AS `t1_is_active` ON main_table.entity_id=t1_is_active.entity_id AND t1_is_active.store_id=0
 LEFT JOIN `magecatalog_category_entity_int` AS `t2_is_active` ON t1_is_active.entity_id = t2_is_active.entity_id AND t1_is_active.attribute_id = t2_is_active.attribute_id AND t2_is_active.store_id = 1 WHERE (main_table.path LIKE '1/2/%') AND (t1_is_active.attribute_id='42') AND ((IF(t2_is_active.value_id > 0, t2_is_active.value, t1_is_active.value))=1)
Trace: #0 /home/company/live/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/company/live/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/company/live/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/company/live/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home/company/live/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/company/live/app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Resource/Catalog/Abstract.php(164): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#6 /home/company/live/app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Resource/Catalog/Category.php(80): Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Abstract->_loadEntities()
#7 /home/company/live/app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php(154): Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Category->getCollection('1')
#8 /home/company/live/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/SitemapController.php(255): Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap->generateXml()
#9 /home/company/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_SitemapController->generateAction()
#10 /home/company/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('generate')
#11 /home/company/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /home/company/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /home/company/live/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /home/company/live/index.php(70): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

**The error only appears in our live shop, in the test shop it works fine, even if I checkout the live shop branch in git and the staging area is clean**

The permission of the sitemap.xml is set to `-rw-rw-rw` in both shops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked down the exact problem code line.

It is inside the function `getCollection()` from the class `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Category`:

```
public function getCollection($storeId)
{
    /* @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    if (!$store) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->_select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        ->where($this->getIdFieldName() . '=?', $store->getRootCategoryId());

    $categoryRow = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->fetchRow($this->_select);
    if (!$categoryRow) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->_select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('main_table' => $this->getMainTable()), array($this->getIdFieldName()))
        ->where('main_table.path LIKE ?', $categoryRow['path'] . '/%');

    $storeId = (int)$store->getId();

    /** @var $urlRewrite Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category_Url_Rewrite_Interface */
    $urlRewrite = $this->_factory->getCategoryUrlRewriteHelper();
    $urlRewrite->joinTableToSelect($this->_select, $storeId);    // <-- Problem is here

    $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'is_active', 1);

    return $this->_loadEntities();
}
```

I workaround it by overriding the method in my own extension and changing the function to this:

```
public function getCollection($storeId)
{
    /* @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    if (!$store) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->_select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        ->where($this->getIdFieldName() . '=?', $store->getRootCategoryId());

    $categoryRow = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->fetchRow($this->_select);
    if (!$categoryRow) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->_select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('main_table' => $this->getMainTable()), array($this->getIdFieldName()))
        ->where('main_table.path LIKE ?', $categoryRow['path'] . '/%');

    $storeId = (int)$store->getId();

    /** @var $urlRewrite Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category_Url_Rewrite_Interface */
    $urlRewrite = $this->_factory->getCategoryUrlRewriteHelper();
    $urlRewrite->joinTableToSelect($this->_select, $storeId);

    // Workaround to fix "Unable to generate sitemap" error only happening on live store
    $this->_select = str_replace("IS NOT NULLurl_rewrite.id_path", "IS NOT NULL AND url_rewrite.id_path", $this->_select);

    $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'is_active', 1);

    return $this->_loadEntities();
}
```

I am still confused why this only happens in my live store even though the code on my dev store is 1:1 the same.

Comment: I've checked in magento 1.9.3.2 and 1.9.4 - in the sql query for category URLs generation the condition "category_id IS NOT NULL" does not exist. Check your Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category_Url_Rewrite::joinTableToSelect() method. If this class doesn't used then something replaced this rewrite helper class using config - see Mage_Catalog_Model_Factory::getCategoryUrlRewriteHelper().

Comment: The config partially forms using the database - with the identical code we can have different behaviour between the live and dev sites.

Comment: Case 2: It is possible to change magento config using files from app/etc directory - we can add this code to app/etc/local.xml inside the <config> : 

    <global>
        <catalog>
            <category>
                <url_rewrite>
                    <helper>catalog/category_url_rewrite_my_class</helper>
                </url_rewrite>
            </category>
        </catalog>
    </global>
and rewrite model will be replaced to own class. Very often the developers adds these configuration files to .gitignore and these files drop out of comparison.

Comment: @sergei.sss, I know, I checked the gitignore but nothing relevant is getting ignored. The app/etc/local.xml does not contain such code

Answer (score 1):

There was an error in your SQL:

```
AND url_rewrite.category_id IS NOT NULLurl_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%'
```

should looks like:

```
AND url_rewrite.category_id IS NOT NULL AND url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%'
```

Possible there was some kind of modifications made by some third-party observer. Take a look at modules installed in your system and check all its observers.

Another modifications could exists inside the `app/code/local` directory (using replace of the core class). Check it too.

Comment: If it is really because of code problem, then why does it work on my dev where the same branch is checked out? The staging areas are clean and nothing is there

Comment: My thougths ... this schould not happen with unmodified code.

Answer (score 0):

Try below to see what is actually causing the error before applying the above solution!;

Open the file;

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/SitemapController.php

Find the line:

> $this->_getSession()->addException($e,
>                       Mage::helper('sitemap')->__('Unable to generate the sitemap.'));

And replace it with:

> $this->_getSession()->addException($e,
>                       $e->getMessage());

and try to see if you can run the sitemap again. hope this should be able to help better!

Comment: lol, how should this solve the bug? You are just changing the way how the error message is outputted.